# задержка без Thread.sleep()

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно сделать задержку в приложении не используя Thread.sleep()
Пример кода:

```
public static void start(){
   .....
   while(true){
   try{
   Thread.sleep(longValue);
   }catch(Exception e){}
   if(A){
     Thread thr = new Thread(new Runnable(){
     @Override
     public void run() {
     while(true){
        ...
        function1()
        try{
        Thread.sleep(longValue1);
        }catch(Exception e){}
     }
    }
    });
    thr.start();
   }
   if(B){
     Thread thr2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
     @Override
     public void run() {
     while(true){
        ...
        function2();
        try{
        Thread.sleep(longValue2);
        }catch(Exception e){}
     }
    }
   });
   thr2.start();
}
}
```

В итоге получается хаос. Когда по условию запускается новый цикл эти задержки работают просто как им вздумается. Ставишь например задержку 2000мс она может продержаться и 20000мс и 2000000мс. Насколько я понял слипать треады не есть хорошо. Гугление не очень помогло. Так как все методы которые нашел реализуются через Thread.sleep(); Подскажите пожалуйста в чем причина такого поведения данного метода, и чем можно его заменить?

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос: нужен аналог шарповского `await Task.Delay(2000)` в джаве под андроид.

Comment: На шарпе не работал, поэтому не знаю про этот метод. Просто нужно что бы эти задержки не превращались в хаос. Что бы было так, что задал ему задержку например в 2000мс, и он именно 2000мс ее и держал, ни больше, ни меньше.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что значит "слипать треады не есть хорошо."?
Слипать GUI-треды - не хорошо. Не изобретайте велосипед и используйте "засыпания" (с правильной обработкой InterruptedException) во второстепенных потоках.
P.S. Для андроида обратите внимание на класс AsyncTask, где обрабатывать логику и "досыпать" нужно в методе doInBackground.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем причина такого поведения Thread.sleep()? По поводу doInBackground сейчас почитаю.

Comment: @leprikon, sleep во всех языках гарантирует задержку не менее заданной, но никак не обеспечивает максимум. Т. е. время прошло, где-то там поток пометился активным, а уж когда его планировщик достанет - неизвестно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, мне кажется, вы путаете sleep и wait

Comment: Неа. Я говорю про внутреннее устройство менеджера потоков.

Comment: Тогда как быть? Может лучше отталкиваться тогда от системных часов? Или это тоже не поможет?

Comment: @leprikon, ваш код сам по себе весьма странен. есть главный цикл, который сам по себе "засыпает" каждую итерацию. И на каждую итерацию в нём в зависимости от условий A и B создаются потоки, выполняющие некоторую работу (при этом видимо не синхронизированно с вызывающим потоком). Внимание - потоки создаются НОВЫЕ на КАЖДУЮ итерацию, но в конце у них почему-то вызывается Thread.sleep(), хотя после этого никакую работу они уже не выполняют

Comment: Мне видится это так. Есть цикл, который каждую итерацию проверяет условия. Если условия1 - true, то запускается поток, в котором так же присутствует цикл. Если условие2 - false, цикл запущенного потока получает это значение и срабатывает break; Конечно может быть такое построение не является верным.

Comment: @leprikon, мне кажется, вы запутались в потоках. попробуйте для начала делать всю работу в одном потоке (в цикле) не плодя новых сущностей. Когда одного потока действительно не хватит (например интерфейс станет неотзывчивым из-за sleep, если это gui-поток) используйте второй поток и синхронизацию (AsyncTask именно про это).
Чтобы добиться стабильности в "задержках" в начале и в конце цикла записывайте System.currentTimeMillis() и вызывайте sleep на значение longValue - (timeEnd - timeBegin);

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное. Вот только что попробовал так сделать. Действительно все работает гораздо точнее и стабильнее. Еще раз очень Вас благодарю.

Answer (score -3):

Например так(задержка будет зависеть от вычислительной мощности процессора):

```
for(int i =0; i<10000; i++)//задежрка в 10000 итераций
    {
      int a = i;
    }
```

или так:

```
int i = 10000;
    while(i>0)
    {
      i--;
    }
```

и еще:

```
 long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5*1000; // задержка в 5 секунд
  while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
      synchronized (this) {
          try {
              wait(endTime - System.currentTimeMillis());
          } catch (Exception e) {
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: А где задержка?

Comment: Это и есть самая простая задержка на 10000 операций. Вставьте эти строки вместо вашего Thread.sleep();
Меняя число 10000 на большее/меньшее можно добиться разной задержки. Чем больше число - тем дольше задержка.

Comment: Спасибо большое за Ваш ответ. А цикл не будет грузить процессор?

Comment: Ужасный вариант. Такая задержка вообще никак ко времени не привязана, будет зависеть от компа конкретного пользователя, да ещё и как только число таких одновременных циклов превысит число ядер процессора, будет тоже в разы замедляться. Это хуже, чем sleep, а не лучше.

Comment: @leprikon, будет, естественно.

Comment: А нет вариантов задержки без использования циклов?

Comment: @leprikon тут конретное время задержи зависит от вычислительной мозщности процессора. Чем мощнее процессор - тем быстрее закончится цикл

Comment: Это я понял. ХОтелось бы конечно контролировать эту задержку, поэтому такой вариант врядли подойдет.  Но все равно спасибо за него)

Comment: @leprikon добавил еще 1 вариант, где можно контроллировать задержку

Comment: Вот спасибо огромное за этот вариант) Кажется все понял. Сейчас попробую реализовать.

Comment: Прекрасный пример того, как ни в коем случае не следует реализовывать задержки.

Comment: @leprikon, пожалуйста, не надо. Иначе, возможно, рефакторингом вашего кода будут пытать людей.

Comment: Понял. Не буду)

Comment: @NikolayRomanov ТС спросил: "чем можно заменить задержку слипом?". На что был дан конкретный ответ. Использовать или нет - дело каждого, но ответ на конкретный вопрос, я считаю, был дан!

Comment: @LionisIAm поймите меня правильно - ваш ответ могут увидеть неопытные программисты и подумать что это действительно адекватная замена. Ваши методы хоть и позволяют "застопорить" текущий поток на самом деле ни в коем случае не должны рассматриватсья как альтернативы. Более того, код `for(int i =0; i<10000; i++)//задежрка в 10000 итераций
    {
      int a = i;
    }` вероятно вообще будет убран при оптимизации как не несущий смысловой нагрузки.